# Copying LaTeX from Mathematica

Tags: latex, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to copy text with `InlineFormula` styles to the clipboard with the math section within the dollar signs?

Take this for example. The following screenshot shows part of a mathematica notebook:

[image: Notebook]

I have duplicated the same cell to show the expression form. Now, when I right click on the text and click copy as LaTeX and paste it say here:

```
\text{I hope this inline text is copied within the dollar signs: }

f(x) = 3. \text{Did} \text{it} \text{work}?
```

I get that. If I were to save the file as latex I would obtain something like this:

```
I hope this inline text is copied within the dollar signs: \(f(x) = 3\). Did it work?
```

I have never used `\( \)` in latex. But I'm assuming this is another form of doing inline math since it worked when I compiled it with LaTeX

Sometimes I find myself typing some text in Mathematica and later pasting some text with inline text into some latex file. Is there some settings I can change so that I can obtain the inline math mode instead of the `\text{}` command?

Another related question is, Is it possible to do display math in Latex? The `DisplayFormula` style doesn't seem to work quite right.

Any knowledge about latex settings in *Mathematica* is welcome.

Comment: Have you looked at [TeXForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TeXForm.html?q=TeXForm&lang=en)?

Comment: @yoda, I don't see how TeXForm can help here given that all it does is change an expression to TeX. Mathematica copying this to latex but it assumes that everything is in math mode instead of text mode. This is why it uses the `\text{}` command to put text.

Comment: Sorry if that didn't help. I didn't have time to read it fully, and thought it was a generic mma latex Q.

Comment: @yoda, man, the second sentence I wrote there doesn't make much sense. Sorry, I meant to say that Mathematica does a good job copying text to latex but it assumes that everything is in math mode. Anyway, I hope someone knows how to make mma think that we are in text mode.

Comment: `\(` and `\)` is the same as `$` and `$`, just making sure that they are being matched evenly.